# R: changing values across multiple tables

Tags: r

I've been searching for a solution here and trying multiple methods to achieve what I want, but to no avail! I would really appreciate some help.

I have several tables with data on different countries. I need to merge these tables by country, but the same country is often referred to differently in each table, so I need to standardize them first.

Example table1:

```
birth_country   mean_age
China           37
Germany         42
```

Example table2:

```
birth_country                   proportion_male
Federal Republic of Germany     54
China, People's Republic of     43
```

So I want to do something like this (which works when I do it as follows for a single table):

```
table1$birth_country[table1$birth_country == "China"] <- "China, People\'s Republic of"
table1$birth_country[table1$birth_country == "Federal Republic of Germany"] <- "Germany"
```

But no matter what I try, I can't seem to apply this sort of process to ALL of my tables. I've tried `lapply` and a `for` loop, in at least ten variations of the following...:

```
        standardizeCountryNames<-function(x){
          x[x == "China"] <- "China, People\'s Republic of"
          x[x == "Federal Republic of Germany"] <- "Germany"
        }

  tables<-list(table1, table2, table3)

 lapply(tables, function(i) {standardizeCountryNames(i$birth_country)})
```

and

```
for (k in 1:length(tables)){

          tables[[k]]$birth_country[tables[[k]]$birth_country == "China"] <- "China, People\'s Republic of" }
```

I've tried referring to the birth_country variable in different ways, such as using `with(table)` and `attach(table)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (:

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
table1 <- read.table(
  text = "birth_country   mean_age
China           37
Germany         42", 
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table2 <- read.table(
  text = 'birth_country                   proportion_male
"Federal Republic of Germany"     54
"China, People\'s Republic of"     43', 
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

standardizeCountryNames<-function(x){
  x$birth_country[x$birth_country == "China"] <- "China, People\'s Republic of"
  x$birth_country[x$birth_country == "Federal Republic of Germany"] <- "Germany"
  x
}

tables<-list(table1, table2)

lapply(tables, function(i) {standardizeCountryNames(i)})
# [[1]]
#                 birth_country mean_age
# 1 China, People's Republic of       37
# 2                     Germany       42
# 
# [[2]]
#                 birth_country proportion_male
# 1                     Germany              54
# 2 China, People's Republic of              43
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! But I'm still having troubles ):

When I format my function and lapply as you did in your response, the output I get is:

'[[1]]
[1] "Gabon Republic"

[[2]]
[1] "Gabon Republic"

[[3]]
[1] "Gabon Republic"'

(One of the lines in my function is:)
x$source_country_or_territory[x$source_country_or_territory == "Gabon"] <- "Gabon Republic"

And when I look at my tables, the country names haven't changed. Not even for Gabon.

Comment: Last line of your function must be `x` (or `return(x)` equivalently). And it won't change values in original tables (and it shouldn't). The result of `lapply(...` should then be affected to `tables <- lapply(...` or `whatever_suits_you <- lapply(...`

Comment: To be honest, I never figured this out--even after trying your suggestions. I gave up and have just been running my function manually for each table in turn. (I appreciate your attempts to help me though!)